# Using LESS with grails lesscss-resource

Tags: grails, plugins, less

I could not find a good explanation to set this up in my grails app. I am running grails 2 with the most recent version of lessees-resource plugin but I cannot find an in depth explanation on how to set this up.

Where do I put the less files?

What will it be compiled to?

How should I link to this compiled source?

I'm sorry if this is an easy question but I have not been able to find good documentation on this at all.

To be specific to what I need I have the entire TwitterBootstrap project less files.

I use Theme.less to override changes by importing all the files to this file and making the changes independent of the actual project to make updating the bootstrap easier.

```
/less
  Theme.less
  Bootstrap/ #The entire twitter bootstrap project
```

how can I get the Theme.less to compile and how do i reference it in my application main layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare your resources files in `ApplicationResources.groovy` file (in `<your_project>/grails-app/conf` folder).

It should look something like this:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
    }

    bootstrap {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        resource url:'js/libs/bootstrap.js'
        resource url:'css/libs/bootstrap.less',attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css']
    }

    yourstyle {
        dependsOn 'bootstrap'
        resource url:'css/theme.less',attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css']
    }
}
```

Note that you can put your less files wherever you want inside `web-app` folder, in this file you configure where they are.

Another thing that you can do if you are overwriting Twitter Bootstrap is to import bootstrap at the beginning of your theme.less file:

```
@import "libs/bootstrap.less";
```

And remove this resource declaration in `ApplicationResources.groovy`. If you do this, it will take longer to compile less file if you make changes when project is running (it has to compile both less files).

To use this modules on your layout (i.e. main.gsp) include this lines of code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        ...
        <r:require module="yourstyle"/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to add the `layoutResources` tag twice to your page, for the  resources and end-of-body resources (Because you can declare where do you want to include your resources, by default at the end of `body` tag). You can read more about how Grails Resources works at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/

Note that 'your style' already depends on 'bootstrap', so you don't need to include both of them in your layout.

Comment: Thank you that clears a lot up. How would I require the modules in my main.gsp layout?

Comment: I had to add bundle:'bootstrap' to get the less files to compile (I combined bootstrap and yourstyle and moved the files to less directory. It is now creating a link to <link href="/mysite/bundle-bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet"/> but i am getting an error saying "Error 2012-11-10 16:38:14,604 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /bundle-bootstrap_head.css".

Comment: Can you copy your code to see how are you declaring and using Bootstrap styles and your own less files?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to add disposition: 'head' to the resource. resource url:"less/theme.less",attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css'], disposition: 'head'

Answer (score 0):

Both less-resources and lesscss-resources are not currently ( march 2014 ) working with less 1.6 which is necessary for building bootstrap 3.1

U can use [asual-lesscss-resources](http://www.grails.org/plugin/asual-lesscss-resources) plugin in same way

```
bootstrap{
    defaultBundle 'bootstrap'
    resource url:[dir: 'less', file: 'bootstrap.less'], attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css']
    resource url: 'js/bootstrap/dropdown.js'
  }
```